# Change the expressionengine publish entry datepicker

Tags: date

As a programming project I have a task to change expressionengine default datepicker for inserting date in publish or edit entry form with a custom one! I know where the default datepicker file is located , but I'm not allowed in any case to replace or change this file , but I need to attach my own jquery datepicker using some extension hook to the expressionengine publish entry date field , but I really don't know how to define my datepicker in expressionengine , and I only need it in the control panel / publish entry / date area! not as a channel field.

PS : the reason to change the current EE datepicker is because we have a very different format for showing date (different year , month etc.) like how chinese date format is different with US!

Comment: What is your date format? Recent versions of EE support three formats: `mm/dd/yy`, `dd-mm-yy`, and `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to prevent default to stop the existing datepicker opening on input click.

You could then use jQuery UI datepicker to add your own datepicker and customise it.